# Using react-redux Provider for React components in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating a website using Angular 2+ but I'd like to also utilise a library of certain React components. That shouldn't really be that hard; however, the catch is that these components require a [react-redux Provider](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) with a Redux store at the root level to work. Basically the document tree should look like:

```
<body>
  ...
  <Provider store={store}>
    <span>
       <app-contents></app-contents>
       <TopLevelComponent/>
    </span>
  </Provider>
  ...
</body>
```

...where `<app-contents>` is an Angular component with most of the website contents, inside of which would be usages of the various React components; and TopLevelComponent is another one of those.

---

First, I tried using [@ngui/react](https://github.com/ng2-ui/react) to render the React components. This seems like it could work for the small components, although they (correctly) complain about the lack of access to a store. But when used for the Provider, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-provider',
  template: `
    <ngui-react [reactComponent]="provider" [reactProps]="{store: theStore}">
      <span>
        <app-provider-contents></app-provider-contents>
        <ngui-react [reactComponent]="topLevelComponent"></ngui-react>
      </span>
    </ngui-react>`
})
export class ProviderComponent {

  provider = Provider;
  topLevelComponent = TopLevelComponent;

  constructor(@Inject(TheStore) public theStore: Redux.Store<any>) {}
}
```

...it result in errors:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
    in Provider
```

and

```
ERROR Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

---

It seems to me like the cause could be @ngui/react being outdated, so I tried to create the Provider dynamically in code:

```
  constructor(@Inject(TheStore) private theStore: Redux.Store<any>,
              private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const contents = React.createElement('app-contents', {key: this.randomKey}, null);
    const provider = React.createElement(Provider, {store: this.theStore, key: this.randomKey}, contents);
    ReactDOM.render(provider, this.elementRef.nativeElement, () => {});
  }

  get randomKey() { /* returns a pseudorandom string */ }
```

This results in:

```
<app-provider _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
   <app-contents></app-contents>
</app-provider>
```

...but `<app-contents>` isn't loaded as an Angular component and it stays empty.

---

Finally, I tried to use this situation and load the Angular component dynamically. There appear to be a lot of solutions for that, but many require the parent element to exist statically, through various directives, @ViewChild and whatnot. When I then found a solution that could insert under a given DOM element:

```
const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ProviderContentComponent);
const node = this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.lastChild;
const component = factory.create(this.viewContainerRef.parentInjector, [], node);
this.viewContainerRef.insert(component.hostView);
```

...it renders the components, but it pops the node out to a higher level and the React components inside it complain about no access to a store once again:

```
<app-provider _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1=""></app-provider>
<app-content _nghost-c2="" ng-version="4.4.4">
  content works!
  <!-- react component missing the store -->
</app-content>
```

---

So, now I wonder, is it actually possible to switch from Angular context, to React Provider, to Angular context, to React components, so that it works? Or will I have to get rid of the React library and make the components natively in Angular?